# Location of RMAN backup

Tags: oracle, rman, oracle-12c

I have two servers. One is DB server another is RMAN Catalog DB server. From my RMAN Catalog, I connect to my remote DB server and I run the backup. Where will the backup files be stored? Will it be in my RMAN catalog db server or the source db?

Comment: How do you actually start your backup?

Answer (score 1):

The backup operation will run on the database server, and the backup pieces may be created on the database server, attached storage disk, a backup server through a 3rd party library (Networker, TSM, etc.), or any other server through network shares (NFS, samba), depending on your configuration.